# Access Workbench at Plug-in Start

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to access the `IWorkbench` at the start of a plug-in to attach a `IPartListener`.

The simplest solution was to add the listener in the `start()` method of the plug-in:

```
public class MyPlugin extends AbstractUIPlugin {

private IPartListener partListener = new MyPartListener();

public void start(BundleContext context) throws PluginException {
        super.start(context);

        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> 
            PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
            .addPartListener(this.partListener));
}
}
```

**The explanation:** `Display#asyncExec` runs the next time the UI thread is free, which is after the workbench was created (since it's already in the process of creating it when an `AbstractUIPlugin` is started).

The code worked well for a while, but after the release other projects using it sometimes failed with:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>      at org.acme.project.MyPlugin.lambda$0(MyPlugin.java:43)
>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)

Evidently in this case the workbench wasn't created yet. I moved the code into the `earlyStartup()` of an `IStartup` implementation and now it works for all projects that had complained before.

Since the start of the plug-ins and creation of the workbench is not deterministic, my question is: Is this the right place? Or is this another NullPointerException (or any other exception) waiting to happen?

Comment: Technically, anything you're calling on that line could be null. Just because there's a workbench doesn't mean there's an active window or active page. What user action causes your plug-in to be started?

Comment: @nitind There's no user action, it's a core bundle that get's started with the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaDoc for the `earlyStartup` method in the `IStartup` class explicitly says it is run after the workbench initializes and describes doing something very similar, so this should be OK.

Javadoc:

> Will be called in a separate thread after the workbench initializes.
>
> Note that most workbench methods must be called in the UI thread since
>   they may access SWT. For example, to obtain the current workbench
>   window, use:

```
 final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
 workbench.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
     if (window != null) {
       // do something
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: But what if the window is null? is it possible this should be done in a loop until the window is not null and at that point, for example, add a listener?

Comment: @releseabe Normally it should not be null, the test is just there so you can do some error reporting if it should happen to be null.