# Eclipse Plugin Development - Detect/Listen File open in editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to detect when a file (of any type) is opened in Eclipse and run some code when that happens.

I've tried with the following code but it seems to be calling the function multiple times:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(new IPartListener2() {
            @Override
            public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
                System.out.println("File opened");
            }
            
        });
    }
});
```

Is there a way to do this in Eclipse RCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IPartListener2.partOpened` is the correct thing to use. Make sure you only set up the listener once.

`partOpened` will be called for all parts, so you will need to check for the ones you are interested in.

```java
@Override
public void partOpened(final IWorkbenchPartReference partRef)
{
  // Check for editor reference and get the editor part

  if (partRef instanceof IEditorReference && 
      partRef.getPart(false) instanceof IEditorPart editorPart) {
     // Example getting current IFile being edited:
     IFile file = editorPart.getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
  }
}
```

Note: Example code uses Java 16 type pattern, for older releases it will need revising.

Also note `Display.asyncExec` is not usually needed to set this up.

Comment: What is the name of the extension point in plugin.xml to attach a class with the code in? I tried the  org.eclipse.core.resources.moveDeleteHook as an experiment but kept getting errors like "There must be exactly 0 or 1 hook extensions defined in the moveDeleteHook extension point." I assume besides this code it is also necessary to modify plugin.xml?

Comment: @releseabe This is not an extension and you don't set it in the plugin.xml. You must call the `addPartListener` method of the `IPartService`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030682/eclipse-plugin-notification-of-when-an-editor-is-opened-in-eclipse?rq=3 asks about a plugin that listens  and the code mentions PartsListener but also does not explain which extension point to use. Is not the question you answered being asked about a plugin ?

Comment: You write a plugin and Java code in the plugin sets up the listener. How the code in the plugin is triggered depends on what you want to do. For example you might use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point if you want the plugin to start when Eclipse starts.

Comment: The IWorkbenchWindow is null if I try to access it in the earlyStartup method of the IStartup-implementing class. Is that because at startup the window does not yet exist? If so, how to deal with this? Is there another extension point besides org.eclipse.ui.startup that can be used if "earlyStartup" is indeed invoked too early?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915010/2670892)